# Returning value in stored procedure with sqlsrv_driver.

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a problem on returning a value in stored procedure with `sqlsrv_driver`.

It is not returning error code value 0 or 1.

The code below is showing the error:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01004
            [SQLSTATE] => 01004
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation
        )

)
```

Plz what is the problem?

Comment: Could you include some of the code where this error pops up?